# String indexing in one column in pandas dataframe using index value from other column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

In a column my Pandas DataFrame I have strings that needs to to limited in length to a value that exist in another column in the same dataframe.

I have tried creating a new column and using normal python string indexing with the other column as the value.

Here is a MWE of the code I'm trying to run:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [[5, 'LONSTRING'], [3, 'LONGERSTRING'], [7, 'LONGESTSTRINGEVER']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['String Limit', 'String'])

df['Short String'] = df['String'][:df['String Limit']]

print(df)
```

I expected a new column with shorter strings:

```
   String Limit             String  Short String
0             5          LONSTRING         LONST
1             3       LONGERSTRING           LON
2             7  LONGESTSTRINGEVER       LONGEST
```

Instead I get a TypeError:

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [0    5
1    3
2    7
Name: String Limit, dtype: int64] of <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

It seems that string indexing can't be done this way because `df['String Limit']` is the whole Series and not just the one row value - but are there any alternative ways of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you need filter all values separately, so use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for loop by rows:

```
df['Short String'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['String'][:x['String Limit']], axis=1)
```

Or use `zip` with list comprehension:

```
df['Short String'] = [x[:y] for x, y in zip(df['String'], df['String Limit'])]
```

---

```
print(df)
   String Limit             String Short String
0             5          LONSTRING        LONST
1             3       LONGERSTRING          LON
2             7  LONGESTSTRINGEVER      LONGEST
```

Comment: Two solutions, oh my! Both work perfectly. I'll try the one that has the shortest runtime for my code. Thank you very much!